# Multiple queries on firebase database fields

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on react-native todo application, where you can add tasks, I want to only display tasks that has not been completed or archived, I'm having some difficulties on querying both fields at the same time, this is my code for querying the fields.

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    // fetch all tasks
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/tasks`) 
    .ref.orderByChild("completed").equalTo(false)
    //.ref.orderByChild("archived").equalTo(false) - This query is not working
    .on("value", snapshot =>
      this.setState({ tasks: snapshot.val(), loading: false })
    );
  }
```

Can I get some assistance on how to check both fields? I'd like to check the fields because I'd like to only display the tasks on default view that has not been completed or archived, as mentioned earlier. I've taken some look at previous related threads, and i'd definitely wouldn't like to change database structure just because of that, I'm rendering the tasks to flatlist, which can be found below:

```
 _FlatListData = data =>
    // data recieved from firebase is (collection) an object with individual tasks
    // as separate objects with firebase-defined-id as the key and actual task object as value
    // Object.entries breaks down the collection into an array of arrays with 2 elements each
    // [0] as the key and [1] as value which is then mapped to get an array of objects combining
    // the data and the key value into a single object
    Object.entries(data)
      .map(d => {
        return { ...d[1], key: d[0] };
      })
      .reverse();

{/* render FlatList only if state.tasks is !empty*/}

        {!!this.state.tasks && (
          <FlatList
            /* Since the data fetched from firebase is not an array but an 
            object it needs to be converted into a workable array first */
            data={this._FlatListData(this.state.tasks)}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TaskCard
                data={item}
                DeleteTask={this.DeleteTask}
                UpdateTask={this.UpdateTask}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
          />
        )}
```

EDIT:
Here's sample json how my structure looks like:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "E9JRDTPLZrSAfc0ERvO0yHJw3am1" : {
      "tasks" : {
        "-LvkpiUO_uxXcf-BYZqk" : {
          "archived" : false,
          "body" : "Test",
          "completed" : true,
          "name" : "Test",
          "timestamp" : 1575998646319
        },
        "-Lvl3qzXylp5H2oOLiaE" : {
          "archived" : true,
          "body" : "Gh",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Gg",
          "timestamp" : 1576002613305
        },
        "-Lvl4YE2E_omKrsOjkZs" : {
          "archived" : false,
          "body" : "Hu",
          "completed" : true,
          "name" : "Bh",
          "timestamp" : 1576002794529
        },
        "-Lvl4woHR5rhtl_JgkBP" : {
          "archived" : true,
          "body" : "Vc",
          "completed" : false,
          "name" : "Bbj",
          "timestamp" : 1576002899308
        }
      }
    },
    "ZqABgFit8YglimXPPZJNoSeea803" : {
      "tasks" : {
        "-Lvg7rT7PfFLx1nzEzgg" : {
          "archived" : false,
          "body" : "Test\nS\nS\nS\nS\nDkdndodn\n\n",
          "completed" : true,
          "name" : "Twdt",
          "timestamp" : 1575919777699
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```